# How can I add an object to a list of objects and keep all the preexisting ones?

Tags: java, hibernate, maven, jpa, orm

I am new to Java and I want to update a List withous losing the products that already are on the list. I am using JPA

**Products List:**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "listOfProducts")
public class ProductsList {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;
    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinTable(
            name = "products_id",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "id_list"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "id_product")
    )
    private Set<Product> products;
```

**Product Entity**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "product")
public class Product {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;
    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinTable(
            name = "tabla_id",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "id_product"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "id_list")
    )
    @JsonIgnore
    private List<ProductsList> productsLists;
```

**List Service**

```
// now it only has the CRUD
```

I couldn't seem to find anything resolving this. I found ways to update the list, but it always end up deleting all the previous products in my list.

Also: for some reason, now it's also asking me to change  `for (j:listaRepository.findById(id)) {` for  `for (j:listaRepository.findById(id);;) {`

Comment: It should probably be something like `products.addAll(...)`. The code you shared is not showing the part where you're trying to add new elements so it's hard to say what might be happening

Comment: Oh, you're right. I've just added the missing piece.

Comment: Try to add the ``@ManyToMany`` relationship on both sides to make it bi-directional. Add an attribute ``productsLists`` to your ``Product`` entity

Comment: @FelixSchildmann I updated the post with my actual code. The problem with this is that now it's throwing an exception: "Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: BEFORE_TRANSACTION_COMPLETION"

Answer (score 0):

This is the method I used to solve this in my Service:

```
 public ListOfProducts addProductToList(Integer idList, Integer idProduct) throws ResourceNotFoundException {

    ListOfProducts listOriginal = listRepository.findById(idList).orElseThrow(()-> new  ResourceNotFoundException("The list of products could not be found."));
    Product product = productRepository.findProductById(idProduct).orElseThrow(()->new ResourceNotFoundException("Product not found"));

    listOriginal.getProducts().add(product);

    listRepository.save(listOriginal);
    LOGGER.info(String.format("Product %s was added to the list with id %s ", idProduct, idList));

    return listOriginal;
}
```